# Using JSP Hot deployment for application that need frequent update

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, hotdeploy

Is using JSP Hot deployment a solution to publish new or updated content to avoid restarting the Java EE server (cannot hot deploy jar)? I should not use JSP to code a lot of java, but do I have any other solution?

Comment: JSPs are a form of hot deployment, being compiled too. Updated content might come from a data base, or maybe generated files, not necessarily in the same web app.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My concern is about using JSP to code java because in a lot of books, they always recommend to use jsp for presentation when talking about application design. This is good, but I just wonder If I will run into issues using JSP to code application logic other than presentation because I need frequent update without restarting tomcat, without Jar hot deployment. There is not a lot of code in each JSP but I will need many jsp.

Comment: Code like filling a `List<Order>` _(data model)_ can be done in a servlet _(controller)_, that does `getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp").forward(request, response)` and setting the data List in a request attribute. JSPs are for the final _view_, doing the templating and showing the data.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But I will need to restart tomcat if I make any changes in the servlet because I only hot deploy JSP. My Idea was to use let say one JSP as controller and then update it without having to restart tomcat. Then in this JSP I will use forward action. I wonder if the only reason for not doing something that is possible is because of design (like MVC).

Comment: Restarting tomcat when the servlets are updated has become a pain because there are other modules that are used, but I need to publish frequent updates...

Comment: You could deploy the war "exploded", with the classes folder editable, then when you make a "java" change, you can replace the compiled class and touch web.xml...theoretically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Tomcat, you can use the **Parallel Deployment** method. You will be able to deploy your new version and keep older one running with every users that has a session on it.

It is really simple when you are using WAR files, I recommend a simple script to delete older versions after couple of days for exemple, just to keep only few running versions.

You can get more informations here : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment

Comment: I did not know that such feature existed. Thanks!

Comment: Nor me since last month :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) yet?